# Form top most?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I display something over all other application. I want to to display something over all form of my program and all other programs open on my desktop (not mine).

***Top Most doesn't work I have tested and my browser can go OVER my application :S**

Here is an image of when I use TopMost to TRUE. You can see my browser is over it...

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5a98165605.png

Comment: Interesting I just tested it on my machine and it works as advertised. (I'm running .NET 3.5 SP1)

Comment: What are your results with Daok's method ?

Comment: Visa here with 3.5 and doesn't work sorry.

Comment: I added an image to the question. You see?

Comment: I saw the image but cannot explain it. I just tested it on another machine with the same result (was on top). What about the answer from Daok did you try that ?

Comment: Doesn't work either :(, I give you both +1 but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the form instance and set the property **TopMost** to True.

---

If you want to be over all Windows, there are another way with **Win32 Api** calls.

Here is what you could do:

In your form class add :

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

In the form load you can add :

```
SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
```

This should do the trick.

### Update

**TopMost** should do the job BUT: Top most OR/AND the Win32 Api call will only work not inside Visual Studio (well for Vista and with VS2008 I tested it... I can't tell for other). Try running the program with the .Exe from the /bin directory, it will works.

Comment: I just tested the TopMost property and it does set it above all windows.

Comment: ^^ aye, this is what I thought at well. What windows trump .TopMost?

Comment: i edited be cause I read in MSDN that that should do that, but in practice I have a project that required more than only TopMost to be at the top. Maybe it was because the form hasn't any title.

Comment: I think SO should add a WORKS ON MY MACHINE feature.

Comment: It works outside VS2008 for me, but inside VS2008 it doesn't. Is it because I am on Vista??? (Thx Daok I might accept you if I have not a solution inside VS2008)

Answer (score 7):

The Form.TopMost property will set your form the top form above all other running windows applications (not just your forms.)

```
myForm.TopMost = true; // This will do the job
```

Answer (score 2):

TopMost property is what you need (never had a problem with that)

---

On MSDN it says:

> A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost) forms even if it is not the active or foreground form. Topmost forms are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the windows on the desktop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my team we had a internal tool that keeps on running after Windows startup. It is a WinForm with TopMost set to ture. On Vista, sometimes we had the same problem. At very random times, the form will lost TopMost property and other non-topmost window can appear above it.
I had a log of researches but found no answer and many other people had this same problem, it seems that on Vista at very low level there is a bug about TopMost property.