# How do i set this window to topmost?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do i set my window above all other? I need a bad but noticeable msg box that closes on its own.
Msg is a dummy form which is empty. All i want is its title.
The problems with the code is the window isnt created 0,0 (its just whereever windows feels like putting it). The width is correct but i notice if i click firefox or another app window my app doesnt pop up. I know it is being shown bc i can see it in the taskbar at the bottom for a brief second. So the bugs so far

1. Doesnt go topmost if i click another app
2. Isnt 0,0

How do i fix this?

```
            {
                var msg = new Msg();
                msg.Text = (has ? "*" : "+") + args[0];
                msg.TopMost = true;
                msg.Width = 2000;
                msg.Top = 0;
                msg.Left = 0;
                msg.Show();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                msg.Close();
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form top most?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324463/form-top-most)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `TopMost` doesn't always do it; here's an answer to a similar question showing how to hook into Win32 for the call: [Form top most?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324463/form-top-most/324464#324464)

---

Update: just read the rest of the answer; it might only fail running in Debug mode within Visual Studio (where your app is actually executed with vshost.exe, rather than running independently).