# Prevent windows based application to steal focus of other application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am stuck up with one of the steal focus issue. My problem is whenever I run my Windows based application, a splash form gets loaded and it holds the overall control/focus of the window screen. During the time it is loaded, if I am trying to open any other application like Word, Notepad, Outlook, browser etc. then my previously running application steals the focus of newly opened applications like Word, Notepad etc. I have tried many things and searched all over the net for a solution.

Comment: Use a background thread to perform your initialization tasks during this splash screen. Don't jeopardize the main GUI thread.

Comment: Try to use the [`Form.TopMost` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx), and see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324463/form-top-most#answer-324464) it might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

In splash screen add this:

```
this.TopMost = false.
```

This is what I understand from your question.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud Gamal and Hooch for your fast and kind replies.But the problem i m application is created in Visual Lansa Technology and as thier is no way of hadling the Form focus so i m creating one ActiveX control using .Net Technology but the question is how can i make use of your suggested solution This.Topmost = false.